# Is there any difference in following 2 jquery code snippet?

Tags: jquery

Is there any difference in following 2 jquery snippet? Both gives same output but does any one have any advantage over other or they are just one's choice to write like this to do the thing.

Snippet 1:

```
div = $("#myDiv");
div.append("<ul>");
$.each(cobj, function(k,v) {
    div.append("<li><span class='"+v+"'>"+k+"</span></li>");
});
div.append("</ul>");
```

Snippet 2:

```
$("<ul>").attr("id", "myUL").appendTo("#myDiv"); 
$.each(cobj, function(k, v) {  
    var li = $("<li>");  
    $("<span>").text(k).attr("class",""+v}).appendTo(li);
    li.appendTo("#myUL");  
});
```

Comment: so hard to understand for me. Why did you not combine all string (like string builder) to make a text then append to "div" tag?

Comment: @vietean : it is similar(not exact) to snippet 1.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that comparing with you combine all string to one than append is better in performance. I think, if you try for peer element the Document (DOM) will try to parse the content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are not good ways to manupulate the DOM tree in terms of performance. I would suggest the following:

```
var ul = $("<ul id='myUL'>");
$.each(cobj, function(k,v) {
    ul.append("<li><span class='"+v+"'>"+k+"</span></li>");
});
$("#myDiv").append(ul);
```

In this way, browser does not re-render page after each li is appended, the entire list is build offline and then appended with single call.

Comment: @HarryJoy Yes, it is, but it's not the same. As I said, the difference is exactly in the performance (try it with 1000 elements in the cobj array).

Answer (score 0):

In 1 the UL has no ID, whereas in 2 it has ID="myUL"

Comment: Nice pick. But this is not actually what I'm looking for? I want to know is there any performance difference between them?

Comment: You do not see the existence or not of an ID as a performance issue?